# My website won't scroll on mobile in laravel

Tags: laravel, mobile, scroll, nicescroll

I have already tested some small things but I can't figure it out.

The website is built in Laravel and uses the nicescroll.js script (I suspect this to be the problem), but I hasn't figured out how to correctly disable it. Simply removing the script will render the site unable to scroll so I think there is an event binder somewhere but I can't find it.

On regular browsers it works fine and scrolls, however on mobile you can only scroll a tiny bit and then if won't let you go further.

If you want to test, the domain is https://develop.fromdoortodoor.nl/

Any suggestions or tips with nicescroll plugin?

Comment: It's best to show some code. Can you show us the nicescroll plugin logic? Try editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

The **niceScroll** code is currently available in your **custom.js** file and is triggered on `$(document).ready`, as follows:

```
$('html').niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#000",
        cursorborder: "0px solid #fff",
        railpadding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0
        },
        cursorwidth: "10px",
        cursorborderradius: "0px",
        cursoropacitymin: 0.2,
        cursoropacitymax: 0.8,
        boxzoom: true,
        horizrailenabled: false,
        zindex: 9999
    });
```

I suggest to disable that portion of code if you really do not need it to be triggered or add a conditional statement for mobile devices.

Answer (score -1):

The website seems to actually scroll fine on my mobile and I don't see a trace of nicescroll.js implementation.
I suggest that you paste a portion of your code or send more information like images.

Comment: Apparently on apple it seems to work fine but on android it isn't. What kind of phone did you use?